# Neo4jRule : Include algorithm plugins (such as randomWalk) to a Neo4j test server

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to test some procedure I have made with the code given by Neo4j for testing procedure. However my procedure is based on the results from the random walk algorithm which I have to call through 'algo.randomWalk.stream()'.

To do so, I'm instantiating a Neo4j test server. However it doesn't recognize the algo.randomWalk.stream(), because I think it doesn't have the algorithm package in its plugins.

This is the code I'm working on

```java
package example;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import static org.neo4j.driver.v1.Values.parameters;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.harness.junit.Neo4jRule;


import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.neo4j.driver.v1.Values.parameters;


public class ScoringTest {
    // This rule starts a Neo4j instance for us
    @Rule
    public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()

            // This is the Procedure we want to test
            .withProcedure( Scoring.class );

    //org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged
    @Test
    public void shouldAllowReturningTheLastValue() throws Throwable
    {
        // This is in a try-block, to make sure we close the driver after the test
        try( Driver driver = GraphDatabase
                .driver( neo4j.boltURI() , Config.build().withEncryptionLevel( Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE ).toConfig() ) )
        {
            System.out.println(neo4j.boltURI().toString());
            // Given
            neo4j.withExtension(neo4j.boltURI().toString(), "..\\graph-algorithms-algo-3.5.4.0.jar");
            Session session = driver.session();
            String PATH = "..\\data\\data.json";
            File JSON_SOURCE = new File(PATH);

            List<HashMap<String,Object>> mss = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, List.class);
            session.run("UNWIND {bulk} as row " + 
                    "CREATE (n:Users) " + 
                    "SET n += row.properties", parameters("bulk", mss ));
            for(int k = 0; k<9; k++) {
                PATH = "..\\data\\"+k+".json";
                mss = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, List.class);
                JSON_SOURCE = new File(PATH);
                session.run("UNWIND {bulk} as row " + 
                        "MATCH (from:Users), (to:Clips) " + 
                        "WHERE ID(from) = toInt(row.from) AND ID(to) = toInt(row.to._key) " + 
                        "CREATE (from)-[rel:hasClipped]->(to) " + 
                        "SET rel += row.properties ", parameters("bulk", mss ));
            }

            // When
            Value result = session.run( "MATCH (n:Clips) WHERE ID(n) = 1038 " + 
                    "CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(ID(n), 2, 1) " + 
                    "YIELD nodeIds " + 
                    "UNWIND nodeIds as nodeId " + 
                    "MATCH (l:Clips)-[r:hasClipped]-(q:Users) " + 
                    "WHERE (ID(l) = nodeId) AND (ID(q) in nodeIds) " + 
                    "WITH collect({relation:r,Clip:l,User:q}) as res " + 
                    "RETURN res").single().get("res");
            System.out.println(result);
            // Then
            assertThat( result, equalTo( 0L ) );
        }
    }

}
```

The exact error that I get is : org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `algo.randomWalk.stream` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Thanks for your time and your future answers,
Syndorik

Answer (score 1):

So I found out a solution for this issue.
There's an option for Neo4jRule object that allows you to change the path to the plugin directory.

For instance, I've just added this config to Neo4jRule and then could call the graphalgo library :

```java
public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()

            // This is the Procedure we want to test
            .withProcedure( Scoring.class )
            .withConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.plugin_dir, "PATH_TO_PLUGIN_DIR")
            .withConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.procedure_unrestricted, "algo.*" );
```